# cakephp's date regular expression matches wrong date

Tags: php, regex, cakephp, cakephp-2.0, pcre

I was checking out cake's library and found a regular expression for date in its Validation.php file. I used it against various date values and found that it even matches wrong date values for some specific dates.

For example, It matches perfectly against following dates (which in fact, **it should**):-

```
20/01/2011
19/09/2017
20/01/1601
```

But when i use a wrong date value with 29 and/or 30 as a date, then surprisingly it matches them too (which **it should not**):-

```
30/,/1601
29/,/2017
```

https://regex101.com/r/8Q96bd/1/

One more interesting thing is, if you change date and use another date except 30 and 29, then expression wouldn't match it.

Use any other date except 29 & 30 and it doesn't match it:-

```
28/,/1600
```

https://regex101.com/r/UKuPWU/1/

Then why on the earth cakephp's date regex expression matches a wrong date value if it contains 30 & 29 as a date?

Here is the expression:-

```
^(?:(?:(?:31(\\\/|-|\\.|\\x20))(?:0?[13578]|1[02]))\1|(?:(?:29|30)([-\/])(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])\2))(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$|^(?:29([-\/])0?2\3(?:(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([-\/])(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))\4(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2})$
```

You can find this expression inside cakephp lib directory (i am using cake 2.x though).

```
\lib\Cake\Utility\Validation.php  (check out its date function)
```

[image]

My doubts are following:-

**1.** Why it is allowing **comma** in place of month **only for 29 & 30?**

**2.** Why it has used **x20** in the regular expression? What is the need of using it in a DATE expression?

**3.** Is there any date standard/rule/specification am i missing which allows 29 & 30 to be used without mentioning month?

Could anyone please help in understanding the logic behind all these things?

Comment: Don't you see the comma in `[1,3-9]`? That is why the comma is matched.

Comment: I understood that but i was trying to understand WHY cakephp would use comma in the first place if others have to remove it later?

Comment: It is a mistake. There are a lot of libraries with regexes, and I have seen such (and other) inaccuracies in them. It is common. There are typos in documentations (yesterday, there was some Django question). There is some site saying you may use `[A-z]` to match all ASCII letters, but in fact, [it is wrong](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29771926/3832970).

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the beautiful explanation and demo. I shall remember it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comma inside a character class is *meaningful* to the regex engine. `[1,3-9]` matches `1`, `,` (!), `3`, `4`, `5`, `6`, `7`, `8` and `9`.

You need to remove that comma.

Besides, there are loads of redundant groupings in the pattern that only prevent the pattern debugging.

Here is a cleaner version of the regex:

```
^(?:31([-\/.\x20])(?:0?[13578]|1[02])\1|(?:29|30)([-\/])(?:0?[13-9]|1[0-2])\2)(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}$|^29([-\/])0?2\3(?:(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00)$|^(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])([-\/])(?:0?[1-9]|1[0-2])\4(?:1[6-9]|[2-9]\d)?\d{2}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6pb4ZU/1)

Note that `\x20` matches a space, the char with decimal code 32. `\x20` is used in order not to introduce a literal whitespace into the pattern so that it could be easily debugged with the `x` (freespacing) modifier when you may add comments to the pattern and break into separate lines (see [example](https://regex101.com/r/6pb4ZU/2)).